# Show that if $X$ is bounded above, then there exists $y \in a + X$ such that $y$ is an upper bound of $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

"Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and $a > 0$. Define

$$a + X = \{a+x: x \in X\}$$

Show that  if $X$ is bounded above, then there exists $y \in a + X$ such that $y$ is an upper bound of $X$"

My approach would be to prove by contradiction:

"Suppose that $X$ is bounded and there is no $y \in a + X$ such that $(y > x)$ $ \forall x \in X$

But then $x + a  \not > x \iff  a \not > 0$

This is a contradiction, since by definition $a > 0$"

However the "hint" in the question suggests that we should prove this by contrapositive. How would I approach this?

Comment: Hint: Every non-empty subset of the reals that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

Comment: i think it's a strange request,to make you prove this by any other means but contradiction. But ok........

Comment: I could not understand the sixth line!!! Could you write down your proof with more explanations?

Comment: @majid By definition, $y = x+a$, and since it is an upper bound then $y > x$ for all values of x. But since I'm making the assumption that y doesn't exist, I'm saying that for all x, y = x + a $\not > x$. Then I subtract x from both sides to get a $\not > $0 but this contradicts the original definition which said $a > 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contrapositive of the statement of the theorem is the natural place to begin.

Let a >0 $\in\mathbb R$. If there is no y$\in$a + X $\subseteq\mathbb R$  such that y is an upper bound of X, then X cannot be bounded above.

Assume X $\subseteq\mathbb R \neq \emptyset$. Let  y$\in a + X$. Assume y cannot be an upper bound for X.Also assume X is bounded above. Since X $\subseteq\mathbb R \neq \emptyset$ and X is bdd above, there exists z$\in \mathbb R$ such that z is the least upper bound of X. This means for every x$\in$X where l$\in\mathbb R$ is an upper bound of x,$1\geq z$ and $z\geq x$. Since a>0, y = a+ x >0.Since z is the least upper bound of X,z$\geq$ x. This means z-x$\geq 0$.If z -x = $0$, then z =x. Then y>z for every y$\in a+X $ But then y is an upper bound of X and we have a contradiction. If z-x >$0$, then there exists l>$0\in\mathbb R$ such that z= l+x. But then since l>$0$, by definition, z$\in$ a+X and again we have a contradiction since z is an upper bound of X! So we're forced to conclude X is not bounded above and we're done. Q.E.D.

P.S. Minor error in the proof. Just corrected it, glad I caught it. Would have been humiliating......